# Progress Bar+Button Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-customview

Доброго времени суток.
Интересует такой вопрос, например я нашел готовую кнопку(проект на GitHub).
Как правильно подключить её и использовать?

Не уверен  можно ли вставлять ссылки, но рискну)
[Git](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1752)

Comment: В [инструкции к проекту](https://github.com/cdflynn/crossview/blob/master/README.md) все предельно ясно написано. И как использовать и как подключить (install). Не понятно что то из того, что там написано? Опишите конкретно, что именно не получается и что вы для этого делали. Каким образом здесь приплюсован `ProgressBar`. Это какой то квест - "догадайтесь сами, что же я хотел" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой найденный компонент или библиотеку нужно в первую очередь подключить к вашему Android проекту - это делается обычно через Gradle (система сборки проекта), в файле настроек:

```
%путь_к_вашему_проекту%\app\build.gradle
```

Компонент который вы нашли подключается добавлением строк:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.cdflynn:crossview:v1.0.1'
}
```

После чего кнопку можно будет использовать в вашей разметке XML layout:

```
<cdflynn.android.library.crossview.CrossView
    android:id="@+id/sample_cross_view"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cross_view_selector"
    app:lineColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Затем делайте импорт библиотеки в вашей активити:

```
import cdflynn.android.library.crossview.CrossView;
```

Объявляйте, инициализируйте и вешайте на OnClickListener:

```
private CrossView mCrossView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    mCrossView = (CrossView) findViewById(R.id.sample_cross_view);
    mCrossView.setOnClickListener(mCrossViewClickListener);
    mCrossView.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cross_view_stroke_color));
}

private final View.OnClickListener mCrossViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCrossView.toggle();
    }
};
```